# Javascript/Jquery: IF Statement always runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

The code always runs when I click the sidebar button. It just keeps on adding 260px each time moving it more to the right. But it should stop after the first click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($('#sidebar').css('left') === '-260px') {   

    $('#btnsidebar').click(function() {
        $('#sidebar').animate({left: '+=260',}, 1000);
    });

    $('#btnsidebar').click(function() {
        $('#btnsidebar').animate({left: '+=260',}, 1000);
    });

}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('#btnsidebar').click(function() {
        if ($('#sidebar').css('left') === '-260px') {    // put if block inside the event
           $('#sidebar').animate({left: '+=260',}, 1000);
           $('#btnsidebar').animate({left: '+=260',}, 1000);  // you are not required to add another click function for doing this
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `if` to the click handler body:

```
$('#btnsidebar').click(function() {
    if ($('#sidebar').css('left') === '-260px')
        $('#btnsidebar').animate({left: '+=260',}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You add these event handlers conditionally, but the action (the animation) inside the event handlers is unconditional. Add an appropriate condition inside the event handlers (you can propably just copy it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your if statement inside not outside.

```
$('#btnsidebar').live('click', function() {
    if ($('#sidebar').css('left') === '-260px') {
        $('#sidebar').animate({
            left: '+=260',
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zXKnr/1/